# How to include MathJax as a dependency

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, mathjax

I'm trying to include MathJax as a dependency in my bower.json or package.json file.  However, I can't find documentation anywhere on how to correctly include it.

I've tried including it like so:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "mathjax": "2.7.5"
}
```

This does not work.
Does anyone know where I could find this information?

Comment: If you're trying to include mathjax in typical build tools, note that v2 does not support that (out of the box).

Comment: I see.  

1) Does an additional tool exist that I can use with MathJax that will support including v2 in typical build tools?  

2) Is there a way to configure MathJax so that it will add this support?

3) If not, does v1 support this?

Comment: 1) not really but you can manually add [a single file build](https://github.com/pkra/MathJax-single-file) 2) MathJax v3 is written in TypeScript which transpiles to all popular module system.

Answer (score 1):

with that you are only including it as a `devDependency`, basically you installed the package using:

> npm install mathjax -D

but what you should do is:

> npm install mathjax --save

with that you will be able to use it.

Comment: So I need mathjax included in either bower.json or package.json so that it can be downloaded with other packages through either "npm install" or "bower install".  I don't want to have to download it individually.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue is to include MathJax in the bower.json file as follows:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "MathJax": "2.7.5"//or replace version number with "latest"
}
```